# PhpStorm autocomplete for OpenCart classes

Tags: ide, phpstorm, opencart

### I did this:

I downloaded a zip from OpenCart website and put it in `xampp/htdocs/mywebsite`. I need PhpStorm to autocomplete methods of OpenCart classes but none are recognized I think. And this is not only for OpenCart: I have the same issue with WordPress as well.

### Edit: check this screenshot

[image]

### I want this:

I want external classes to support autocomplete but I don't know what to do.

Comment: 1) *"I downloaded a zip from OpenCart website and put it in xampp/htdocs/mywebsite"* Extra them from ZIP archive first? 2) In any case: if those files are not part of the project then you can use **Include Paths** https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-include-paths.html (recommended, since you should not be editing those files) .. or additional **Content Root** if you so desire https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-content-roots.html

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for your comment, but it did not worked.

Comment: What type is `model_catalog_manufacturer`? How is it declared? What type that is? What PhpStorm knows about it? What it will show when you place a caret on it and invoke `View | Quick Documentation` (`Ctrl+Q` on Windows in most keymaps). Right now it kooks like IDE does not know what type that is and therefore cannot help here.

Comment: @LazyOne
hi again. long time ha? sorry. I was doing opencart as an intern. and i know how its working now. the models are generated dynamic. so it wont be traceable by any IDE.

Comment: *"the models are generated dynamic. so it wont be traceable by any IDE."* It depends. PHPDoc comments like `@property` should still help (based on my limited understanding or how this works).

Comment: what i mean is that we dont load the model directly. or we dont create an instance form it. we load it via a loader method of base controller. as a property of the parent controller class. so this way, because it does not belong to a exact class we cant trace it.

Comment: If you have a child class where those instances are used then you can use PHPDoc in this child class and declare such instance there (using PHPDoc only, not a real PHP code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

So after a year and half practicing opencart, i can now answer this question. In opencart we have a folder called 'model'. there are files in this folder which you can call in any 'controller' you want. And this models are generated dynamicly. Because of that you cant trace them in IDE, like click on them and see the exact file. Thats why opencart sucks.

Comment: there are a number of folks that create libs which use (or code-generate) phpdoc to try to handle the autocompletes. But generally they have to be aware of what's there which means they may not get extensions unless you autogenerate code any time you add a new extension)